# Rcpp::rmultinom with a pointer to a matrix subview

Tags: rcpp, armadillo

To sample from a Multinomial distribution in Rcpp we can do:

```
int n = 100;
int k = 3;
arma::vec probs = {0.4,0.2,0.4}
arma::irowvec c(k);
Rcpp::rmultinom(n, probs.begin(), k, c.begin());
```

I would like to know whether we can do the same when C is a matrix. I try

```
int n = 100;
int k = 3;
arma::vec probs = {0.4,0.2,0.4}
# C (arma::mat C) passed by reference to the function
Rcpp::rmultinom(n, probs.begin(), k, C.row(1).begin());
```

but it throws an error. Is there a simple way to do it?

I want to try the second approach because I have a big matrix C that I pass by reference to my function, and then I want to update its rows following a Multinomial.

MWE:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

void subfunction(const arma::imat& C) {

  int n = 100;
  int k = 3;
  arma::vec probs = {0.4,0.2,0.4};

  rmultinom(n, probs.begin(), k, C.col(1).begin());
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::imat myfunction(){

  arma::imat C = { {1, 2}, 
                  {3, 4},
                  {5, 6}};
  subfunction(C);
  Rcpp::Rcout << "C: " <<  C << std::endl;

}
```

The error is:

```
test_multim.cpp:18:44: error: ‘class arma::subview_col<int>’ 
has no member named ‘begin’
rmultinom(n, probs.begin(), k, Ct.col(1).begin());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem has two issues:

1. Types required by the `rmultinom` function definition.
2. Accessing a memory pointer for an `armadillo` matrix.

---

To start, note that one of the errors is:

```
mondayso.cpp:16:3: error: no matching function for call to 'Rf_rmultinom'
  rmultinom(1, probs.begin(), k, C.colptr(1));
  ^~~~~~~~~
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/Rmath.h:468:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'double *' to 'int *' for 4th argument
void    rmultinom(int, double*, int, int*);
        ^
1 error generated.
```

In essence, the `rmultinorm` function *must* have an integer being passed in on the 4th argument. Due to the construction of [`arma::mat`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat) being `double` by default, the matrix's *type* is inappropriate. In this case, the `C` matrix must be [`arma::imat`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat) since it uses the [`arma::sword`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#uword) or signed `int` component.

Next, the data for [`armadillo` matrices is stored in a column-by-column order](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat) (See [Wikipedia's entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order#Column-major_order) for details). This means that pointers can only be **easily** established by *column* via [`.colptr`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#colptr). This addresses the second error that arose:

```
error: no member named 'begin' in 'arma::subview_row<int>'
  rmultinom(n, probs.begin(), k, C.row(1).begin());
                                 ~~~~~~~~ ^
1 error generated.
```

Having said this, I've constructed an example that facilitates the transform.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::imat test() {

  int n = 100;
  int k = 3;
  arma::vec probs = {0.4,0.2,0.4};

  arma::imat C = { {1, 3, 5},
                  {2, 4, 6} };

  arma::imat Ct = C.t();

  // C++ indices start at 0 (thus, this is the second column!)
  rmultinom(n, probs.begin(), k, Ct.colptr(1));

  return Ct;
}
```

Test

```
set.seed(111)
test()
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1   43
# [2,]    3   18
# [3,]    5   39
```

Comment: Thanks coatless and @Dirk. It works now thanks to C.colptr (I added the missing MWE)